# Using a custom Unit in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am working on a SAPUI5 freestyle app where I have to implement a custom `sap.ui.model.type.Unit`. So what I did is the following:

In my `onInit`, I am binding the value-property of an `sap.m.Input` like this:

```js
this.byId("input").bindValue({
  parts: ["test>/arbeit/value", "test>/arbeit/unit"],
  type: "sap.ui.model.type.Unit",
  constraints: {
    precision: "7",
    scale: "1",
    minimum: "0,25",
  },
  formatOptions: {
    decimals: "1",
    customUnits: {
      H: {
        displayName: "H",
        "unitPattern-count-one": "{0} H",
        "unitPattern-count-other": "{0} H",
        decimals: "1",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

This works like a charm, when reading data from a model like this JSON:

```
{
  "selected": true,
  "arbeit": {
    "value": 10.0,
    "unit": "H"
  },
  "currency": {
    "value": 10.0,
    "unit": "EUR"
  }
}
```

But as soon as I enter a new value (e.g. `20`) into the input field, I get an assertion error which says:

> assert-dbg.js?eval:34 Assertion failed: Cannot find unit for input: '20'

So I debugged the `Numberformat` and the `UnitType` and I compared it to the `sap.ui.model.type.Currency` and somehow when I enter a new value in a currency-typed field, the currency is getting concatenated to the entered value like **20 -> 20 EUR** and only after that, it gets parsed.

I want this exact behavior with my custom unit-type.

I only get no error when I enter a value **with** the unit together like **10 H**. But I don't want to enter the unit each time I enter a new value.

I hope you guys understand what my problem is. Do you know what I am missing?